A doubt on deducing the equation of an ellipse
In every deduction of an elliptic equation something is strange for me. Lets focus on ellipse centered on $(x_c, y_c)$ with the big axis parallel to the axis $Ox$. Let $F_1 := (x_c - c, y_c)$ and $F_2 := (x_c + c, y_c)$ be the focus. A point $P$ belongs to the ellipse if and only if, $d(P, F_1) + d(P, F_2) = 2a$, that is, if and only if
$$
 (1) \quad \sqrt{[x - (x_c - c)]^2 + (y - y_c)^2} + \sqrt{[x - (x_c + c)]^2 + (y - y_c)^2} = 2a.
 $$
Denoting $s = x - x_c$ e $ t = y - y_c$, last expresion is equivalent to
$$
 (2) \quad \sqrt{(s + c)^2 + t^2}  = 2a - \sqrt{(s - c)^2 + t^2}.
 $$
Now we square both sides
$$
 (3) \quad s^2 + 2 sc + c^2 + t^2  = 4a^2 - 4a\sqrt{(s - c)^2 + t^2} + s^2 - 2 sc + c^2 + t^2,
 $$
which implies
$$
(4) \quad a\sqrt{(s - c)^2 + t^2}  = a^2 -  sc.
$$
Squaring both sides again we obtain
$$
(5) \quad a^2(s^2 - 2sc + c^2 + t^2)  = a^4 - 2a^2 sc + s^2c^2,
$$
that is
$$
a^2s^2 + a^2c^2 + a^2t^2  = a^4 + (sc)^2 \implies a^2s^2 - s^2c^2  + a^2t^2  = a^4 - a^2c^2.
$$
Notice that $a^2 = b^2 + c^2$ and so
$$
\implies  s^2(a^2 - c^2)  + a^2t^2  = a^2(a^2 - c^2)  \implies s^2 b^2  + a^2t^2  = a^2b^2.  
$$
Then
$$
\frac{s^2}{a^2}  + \frac{t^2}{b^2}  = 1,
$$
which implies
$$
(6) \quad \frac{(x-x_c)^2}{a^2}  + \frac{(y-y_c)^2}{b^2}  = 1.
$$
My doubt: If a point $(x,y)$ verifies equation $(6)$, how to make the reverse process in order to see that $P = (x,y)$ verifies $(1)$ ? Precisly, how to go from (5) to $(4)$ and from $(3)$ to $(2)$? My doubt is with the modules that will appers.

Great exposition! It's always a pleasure to learn something!
For real numbers $\; A^2 = B^2\enspace  \Longleftrightarrow\enspace \lvert A\rvert = \lvert B\rvert \enspace  \Longleftrightarrow\enspace \left\lbrace \begin{aligned}A &= B\\ \text{or }\; A &= -B \end{aligned} \right.$.
In order to exclude one alternative, one must simply have a sign condition, i.e. an inequality.
An inequality by Young says that $\lvert s \rvert c \leq \frac{s^2}{2} + \frac{c^2}{2}$ so dividing by $a^2$ yields
$$ \left\lvert \frac{sc}{a^2}\right\rvert\leq \frac{s^2}{2\, a^2} + \frac{c^2}{2\, a^2} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{s^2}{a^2} + \frac{a^2 - b^2}{a^2} \right) \leq \frac{1}{2}(1+1)$$
This implies that $\; sc \leq a^2\quad \Longleftrightarrow\quad a^2 - sc \geq 0$.
Similarly, to go from (3) to (2): use that $\enspace \left\lbrace \begin{aligned} & 0\leq \lvert s \rvert , c < a\quad \Longrightarrow\quad (s-c)^2 < a^2\\
& a^2= b^2 + c^2 \quad \Longrightarrow\quad b \leq a
\end{aligned}\right.$, hence
$$ \frac{\sqrt{(s-c)^2 + t^2}}{a} =\sqrt{\frac{(s-c)^2}{a^2} + \frac{t^2}{a^2}} \leq \sqrt{1 + \frac{t^2}{b^2}} \leq \sqrt{2} < 2$$
So we know that both sides of (2) have the same sign.

There is indeed a mistake in the last step ($s$ can be negative, so that $(s-c)^2$ could in fact be equal to $(-a-c)^2 > a^2$: one can use instead
$$\frac{s^2}{a^2} +\frac{t^2}{b^2}=1\quad \Longrightarrow\quad t^2 = b^2 \left(1 - \frac{s^2}{a^2}\right) = b^2 - s^2\,\frac{b^2}{a^2}$$
so that
$$ \begin{split} 
(s-c)^2 + t^2 &= s^2 - 2 sc + c^2 + b^2 - s^2\,\frac{b^2}{a^2} = s^2 \left(1 - \frac{b^2}{a^2}\right) - 2 s c + a^2\\
&= \frac{s^2 (a^2 - b^2)}{a^2} - 2 s c + a^2 = sc \left( \frac{sc}{a^2} - 2 \right) + a^2
\end{split}$$
$$\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{\sqrt{(s-c)^2 + t^2}}{a} = \sqrt{ \frac{sc}{a^2} \left( \frac{sc}{a^2} - 2 \right) + 1} $$
But
$$ \left\lbrace \begin{aligned}
  0 \leq &\left(\frac{sc}{a^2} \right)^2 \leq 1\\
 -1 \leq \frac{sc}{a^2} \leq 1\enspace &\Rightarrow\enspace 2 \geq -2\, \frac{sc}{a^2} \geq -2
\end{aligned}\right. \quad \Longrightarrow\quad -2 \leq \left(\frac{sc}{a^2} \right)^2 -2\, \frac{sc}{a^2}\leq 3$$
$$\Longrightarrow\quad -1 \leq  \frac{sc}{a^2} \left( \frac{sc}{a^2} - 2 \right) + 1 \leq 4$$
(It should be positive, if there is no mistake in the equality with $(s-c)^2 + t^2$). Ok, square root less or equal to 2.

Perfect solution! Thank you.

Sorry, but I tried but I could not see how to prove that $(s-c)^2 < a^2$. Do I have to prove that $s^2 - 2sc \leq 0$? Because if this is true, I use that $c^2 < a^2$ to conclude. Is this the right way to go ?

I saw the new justification and I liked. However I found another way to justify (3) $\implies$ (2). You proved that $|sc| \leq a^2$ and so (5) $\implies$ (4), because $a^2 - sc > 0$. Now we use the formula given in (4) (now it is true) to prove (3) $\implies$ (2). From (4),
$$ 2a - \sqrt{(s-c)^2 + t^2} = 2a - \left(\frac{a^2 - sc}{a}\right) = \frac{(a^2 + sc)}{a} \geq 0$$
because $-sc \leq |sc| \leq a^2$ and $a^2 + sc \geq 0$.

Great!!! You're teaching this material?

No, I am not. I just needed this detail for a exam where I need to deduce the equation. Of course, when I teach,  I will include this detail.
